# spring boot h2 console connect mem testdb fail

Tags: spring-boot, h2

Today I encountered a very strange situation. I started my spring boot project, and wanted to access h2 console(http://localhost:8081/h2-console).
Everything is ok now, unitl I cliked Connect button.

[image]

Connected failed, it gave me below message:

```
Wrong user name or password [28000-190] 28000/28000 (Help)
```

But before I have connected successfully, and meantime the same project I deployed at another server, and access that h2 console, I still could connect successfully.

And if I changed another db name , e.g. jdbc:h2:mem:foo;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1, this time I can connect it suceesfully.

Now I'm very confused what's wrong with my local embeded h2, why I can't connect default testdb?

Comment: is the User Name still "sa" and password is empty ?

Comment: I have't set another user name  and password explicitly in application.properties. And if I change another dbname, e.g. foo, it could connect successfuly

Comment: might be browser-cache related, try deleting the cache or check with another browser (you know, the one who-must-not-be-named)

Comment: and by the way: which version of Spring-Boot 1.3 do you use ?

Comment: I use firefox to access it, still can't connect testdb. I let my colleague access my server(http://myIp:8082/h2-console/), it hints: Sorry, remote connections ('webAllowOthers') are disabled on this server. But I cloud access h2 console at cloud(my project deployed on cloud).  I used 1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Comment: using a snapshot version is a bad idea, you should use the latest non-SNAPSHOT version which is 1.3.0.RC1. By default, H2 console cannot be accessed from outside your own computer (localhost) which is why you have the "webAllowOthers" disabled. your deployed project must have another config or use a proxy to simulate a localhost connection.

Comment: I used 1.3.0.RC1, no surprise, I changed another h2 version--1.4.189, still no surprise,I even changed jettty to tomcat no surprise again.

Comment: hi, I finally find why is so, all my fault. Because I and my colleague developed on the same spring boot project, but we have different db password, to avoiding update application.properties after every git pull, I set an environment on my computer, export SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=123456, I forgot it after some days. Then suddenly one day I run spring boot data jpa sample, find I cannot connect to testdb on h2 console, and I still could connect another db name like foo and this also mislead me let me think it's other reason.